# jspm can't install from npm

Tags: npm, http-proxy, jspm

Fresh install of both npm (5.4.2) and jspm (0.16.53).

Running **npm install** works correctly.

When running "**jspm install jquery**" fails with the result below:

[image]

However, jspm does work when calling **github**

"jspm install github:github/fetch"

I am behind a corporate proxy, and have set my System Environment Variables -  HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY to the correct address.

.jspm config

```
{
 "defaultTranspiler": "babel",
 "defaultRegistry": "jspm",
 "strictSSL": false,
 "registries": {
   "github": {
   "handler": "jspm-github",
   "remote": "https://github.jspm.io"
 },
 "npm": {
  "handler": "jspm-npm",
  "remote": "https://npm.jspm.io"
},
"jspm": {
   "timeouts": {
    "lookup": 60,
    "build": 120
   },
    "handler": "jspm-registry",
    "remote": "https://registry.jspm.io"
  }
 }  
}
```

Comment: Just wondering, why are you using JSPM? Is it a work requirement or something?

Comment: yeah work requirement, it's part of an app I took over

Comment: dang bro, that's a bummer. I wonder if moving the thing over to NPM might end up saving you time in the long run?